# How to use SQL to get column count for a previous date?

Tags: sql, window-functions

I have the following table,

```
id    status   price      date
2    complete   10    2020-01-01 10:10:10
2    complete   20    2020-02-02 10:10:10
2    complete   10    2020-03-03 10:10:10
3    complete   10    2020-04-04 10:10:10
4    complete   10    2020-05-05 10:10:10
```

Required output,

```
id  status_count   price   ratio
2        0          0        0
2        1         10        0
2        2         30       0.33
```

> I am looking to add the price for previous row. Row 1 is 0 because it has no previous row value.
> Find ratio ie 10/30=0.33

Comment: I removed the conflicting database tags. If you need a solution for a specific database product, please tag **only** that. If you are looking for a database independent solution ("standard SQL") then keep only the `sql` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use analytical function `ROW_NUMBER` and `SUM` as follows:

```
SELECT
    id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) - 1 AS status_count,
    COALESCE(SUM(price) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date), 0) - price as price
FROM yourTable;
```

[DB<>Fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5e4f4ed6bc1947dd2ac24b528aaf3b35)

Comment: I updated the question. Your query works. There was an addition

Comment: Nice trick for the `price`.  I learned something today.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) - 1 AS status_count,
    COALESCE(SUM(price) OVER (PARTITION BY id
                              ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN
                              UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 0) price
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: I updated the question. Your query works. There was an addition of ratio

Answer (score -1):

Please also check another method:

```
with cte 
as(*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) - 1 AS status_count,
SUM(price) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) ss from yourTable)

select id,status_count,isnull(ss,0)-price price
from cte
```